# Perl 6 $*ARGFILES.handles in binary mode?

Tags: raku

I'm trying out $*ARGFILES.handles and it seems that it opens the files in binary mode.

I'm writing a zip-merge program, that prints one line from each file until there are no more lines to read.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl6

my @handles = $*ARGFILES.handles;

# say $_.encoding for @handles;

while @handles
{
  my $handle = @handles.shift;
  say $handle.get;
  @handles.push($handle) unless $handle.eof;
}
```

I invoke it like this: zip-merge person-say3 repeat repeat2

It fails with:  Cannot do 'get' on a handle in binary mode in block  at ./zip-merge line 7

The specified files are text files (encoded in utf8), and I get the error message for non-executable files as well as executable ones (with perl6 code).

The commented out line says utf8 for every file I give it, so they should not be binary,

perl6 -v: This is Rakudo version 2018.10 built on MoarVM version 2018.10

Have I done something wrong, or have I uncovered an error?

Comment: Can you please provide a sample file or files?

Comment: Save the program as "zip-merge" and run it on itself with "zip-merge zip-merge".

Answer (score 3):

The IO::Handle objects that `.handles` returns are closed.

```perl6
my @*ARGS = 'test.p6';
my @handles = $*ARGFILES.handles;
for @handles { say $_ }
# IO::Handle<"test.p6".IO>(closed)
```

If you just want get your code to work, add the following line after assigning to `@handles`.

```perl6
.open for @handles;
```

The reason for this is the iterator for `.handles` is written in terms of `IO::CatHandle.next-handle` which opens the current handle, and closes the previous handle.
The problem is that all of them get a chance to be both the current handle, and the previous handle before you get a chance to do any work on them.
(Perhaps `.next-handle` and/or `.handles` needs a `:!close` parameter.)

---

Assuming you want it to work like [`roundrobin`](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/roundrobin) I would actually write it more like this:

```perl6
# /usr/bin/env perl6
use v6.d;

my @handles = $*ARGFILES.handles;

# a sequence of line sequences
my $line-seqs = @handles.map(*.open.lines);
# Seq.new(
#   Seq.new( '# /usr/bin/env perl6', 'use v6.d' ), # first file
#   Seq.new( 'foo', 'bar', 'baz' ),                # second file
# )

for flat roundrobin $line-seqs {
  .say
}

# `roundrobin` without `flat` would give the following result

# ('# /usr/bin/env perl6', 'foo'),
# ('use v6.d', 'bar'),
# ('baz')
```

If you used an array for `$line-seqs`, you will need to de-itemize (`.<>`) the values before passing them to [`roundrobin`](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/roundrobin).

```perl6
for flat roundrobin @line-seqs.map(*.<>) {
  .say
}
```

---

Actually I personally would be more likely to write something similar to this (long) one-liner.

```perl6
$*ARGFILES.handles.eager».open».lines.&roundrobin.flat.map: *.put
```

Comment: In my code the handles are open.  

A little test shows that:  

    say $_ for $*ARGFILES.handles;

Invoke it with an existingfile, e.g. "ack6":

    ./argfile-handle ack6

IO::Handle<"ack6".IO>(opened)  

The problem is that they are opened in binary mode.

Comment: @ArneSommer Yeah I went over this. The way the iterator is written they get opened and closed as part of that iteration. It is only open during the iteration; they all end up closed afterwards. Also there is a bug that `.get` returns the wrong error. They are not in binary mode. Try calling `read` if you don't believe me.

Comment: @ArneSommer As further proof: `say $_ for flat $*ARGFILES.handles.rotor(2 => -1,:partial);` Which will alternate between saying it is opened and and saying it is closed.

Comment: Thank you. The error message is LTA. It is been tickeded I hope?

Answer (score 1):

`:bin` is [always set in this type of objects](https://docs.perl6.org/language/variables#index-entry-%24%2AARGFILES). Since you are working on the handles, you should either read line by line as instructed on the example, or reset the handle so that it's not in binary mode.

Comment: Ok. I had not seen that section. But it says that it is binary if $*IN is used, and this is @*ARGS and not $*IN.

Comment: Using .encoding on the handles gives "utf8", which it surely wouldn't give for files opened in binary mode?

Comment: What do you mean by "reading line by line"? Surely I'm doing that. Changing `$handle.get;` to `$handle.lines: 1;` (as done in the example) fails as well.

Comment: I think the intent of that line is that if `$*ARGFILES` is using `$*IN` that it copies those attributes from `$*IN`.

Comment: They are not in binary mode, it is a bug that it returns that error. For them to be in binary mode the `encoding` would be `Nil`, that is not the case. Just run `.encoding.say for @handles;` and it will say `utf8` for all of them.